# Will C++ application in .net VS 2003 with no framework reference work without framework 1.1?

Tags: c++, .net, frameworks

I have a C++ application developed in **Visual Studio .net 2003**. It **does not** make use of any framework dlls as references to it. 
The question I have now is , since my project doesnot refer to any framework dll, will it work if framework 1.1 is uninstalled from the system? . I cannot test it myself since I cannot re-install it again due to restrictions on my system.

Answer (score 0):

You mean C++ application, that is not compiled with /CLR option on? Yes, it doesn't need any .NET framework.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Yossarian. Yes , I mean the application with 'Use managed extension' set to NO